# In Python, how do I check if a domain name is taken?

Tags: python, linux, unix, whois

I want to whois "abc.us" or "abc.ly" and see if it's taken.

How do I hit it and see if it's taken, using python?

Comment: Asking what whois DB? I assume that you mean checking official records and not "hitting the domain's servers". That of course would bring false negatives, since servers might be down or non existent in case of name hoarders :D

Comment: I think the concept you want to look at is popen - it opens a pipe to the shell and allows you to read write to the shell - so you can run Whois abc.com and retrieve the results for later processing.

Comment: why is this 'not a real question'? since I can't answer - I'll comment - you should implement whois in python : (a 3.x version - http://www.breaknenter.org/2011/01/a-quick-python-3-whois-implementation/)

Comment: You can't "hit it" because it may be taken while not actually being used. So the only way is to query the whois database. You should also check the T&C's of the whois database before you start doing your automated queries

Comment: This is a funny non-question, since it has a very good, pertinent and accepted answer.